# pyqt: dynamically update properties for dynamically created widgets

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to find a way to update labels which are within dynamically created widgets (that can be deleted), according to properties dynamically set in the preceding widgets.

Is there a way to automatically and dynamically link a pyqt object to a property of other widgets, so that when I change a value anywhere, that object updates itself?

Example: object 'a' has property `start`, `bars` and `end`; `bars` is given, `start` is taken by the previous object (or 1 if None), `end` is calculated. object 'b' takes its `start` from `a.end` and so on.

```
class myclass(object):
  def __init__(self, referrer=None, value=1):
    self.referrer=referrer
    self.value=value

  def _get_start(self):
    if not self.referrer:
      return 1
    else:
      return self.referrer.end+1

  def _get_end(self):
    return self.start+self.value-1

  start=property(_get_start)
  end=property(_get_end)

def create(value=1):
  if not vList:
    ref=None
  else:
    ref=vList[-1]
  val=myclass(ref, value)
  vList.append(val)

def showList():
  for i in vList:
    print 'item: %d\tstart: %d\tend: %d' % (vList.index(i),i.start, i.end)

vList=[]
```

If I call create() 3 times, showList() will show:

```
item: 0 start: 1        end: 1
item: 1 start: 2        end: 2
item: 2 start: 3        end: 3
```

if I change vList[0].value to 3:

```
item: 0 start: 1        end: 3
item: 1 start: 4        end: 4
item: 2 start: 5        end: 5
```

The problem raises when I need to keep those values updated in the gui ([think to it as an interface like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyU8Y.png)): every horizontal widget has a label showing the property of `start`, a spinbox for `bars`,  and a label for `end`, and as soon as **any** spinbox value changes, every subsequent widget should update its `start` and `end` properties according to its previous widget and show them in the relative labels.
Moreover, when any widget is deleted, all the subsequent widget should recompute every property.

Using getter/setter to set the values in the labels of the widgets' next instancies doesn't obviously work as I need, because when I change any `x.value`, the following instancies' `start` and `end` will be actually updated only when recalled, AFAIU.
I could connect every new widget to its previous (with `valueChanged()`) or create a function which finds the subsequent widget and update their properties, but that's not a good solution.

Since I am almost new to python (most important: I'm not a programmer) I think that I am ignoring something about "connecting" variables in a better and cleanest way (maybe related to signals or threading?).

Consider that those widgets will actually be children widgets of another "main" widget, which will have similar properties: `start` taken from its previous main widget (if any), `bars` which is the sum of all `bars` in every children widget, `end` which will be again `start+bars-a`.

Thanks!

(I hope you will understand what I meant, my english is not perfect and, since I'm not a programmer, my terminology is not always correct)

Comment: Your question is detailed. It is very difficult to ascertain what you need help with. Try to distill this to a use case you are having trouble with, start with your question, then demonstrate an example.

Comment: I was afraid of that, sorry. I'm going to rewrite it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find use case for things from your question, but here is possible solution using Qt Signals-Slots:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import functools

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class ObservableVariable(QtCore.QObject):
    """ Represents variable with value, when value changes it emits
    signal: changed(new_value)
    """
    changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
        super(ObservableVariable, self).__init__()
        self._value = initial_value

    def get_value(self):
        return self._value

    def set_value(self, new_val):
        self._value = new_val
        self.changed.emit(new_val)

    value = property(get_value, set_value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    # it can support more operators if needed
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value += other
        return self

    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.value -= other
        return self


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, referrer=None, value=1):
        self.referrer = referrer
        self.value = ObservableVariable(value)
        self._initial_value = value
        if referrer:
            # propagate referrer changes to subscribers
            referrer.value.changed.connect(
                lambda x: self.value.changed.emit(self.value.value)
            )

    @property
    def start(self):
        if not self.referrer:
            return self.value.value
        return self.referrer.end + 1

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self.start + self.value.value - 1


class GuiExample(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GuiExample, self).__init__()
        self.values = []
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        obj = None
        for i in range(5):
            obj = MyClass(obj, i)
            self.values.append(obj)
            # create gui elements
            hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            spinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
            spinbox.setValue(obj.value.value)
            start_label = QtGui.QLabel()
            end_label = QtGui.QLabel()
            hlayout.addWidget(start_label)
            hlayout.addWidget(spinbox)
            hlayout.addWidget(end_label)
            layout.addLayout(hlayout)

            # function called on value change
            def update_start_end(instance, start_label, end_label):
                start_label.setText(str(instance.start))
                end_label.setText(str(instance.end))

            action = functools.partial(update_start_end, obj, start_label,
                                       end_label)
            action()  # set initial start end text to labels
            # connect signals to gui elements
            obj.value.changed.connect(action)
            spinbox.valueChanged.connect(obj.value.set_value)
            obj.value.changed.connect(spinbox.setValue)
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('test',
                                           clicked=self.test_modification))

    def test_modification(self):
        self.values[1].value += 1


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
gui = GuiExample()
gui.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Wow, it looks like what I was looking for. It took a moment to understand how you assigned the referrer (didn't realize the assignment order of `obj`), but now I've understood everything. Now I've to decide if I want to assign every new referrer by hand (when I delete or insert widgets in the middle of the list), but maybe I can find a way to 'connect' them automatically using the `values` list.
Thank you so much!